# AtomicLong equivalent in Dart

Tags: concurrency, dart

HI i am looking for [AtomicLong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) equivalent in dart please let me know if there is another way to achieve this in dart

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for that in Dart. Dart is single-threaded and all updated are atomic.

Comment: I can think of a situation where you have 2 async methods writing the same variable where you need atomicity unless it's provided by the dart compiler. Are you saying that all write instructions are atomic in dart or that because it's single threaded there is no need? Because while it's not MT it can still be concurrent

Comment: How can it be concurrent? No matter how many pending futures you have, only one callback can be executed at a time. When a future completes its callback is enqueued and only executed when the previous callback is completed. With callback I mean the function you pass to then(...) or the code after an awaited statement/expression. Without threads there just can't be any concurrency. No code is ever interrupted. It has to yield or complete before another callback can be executed.

Comment: You are right, I did not yet understand concurrency in Dart completely. There is concurrency but not a need for atomics because code blocks are not interrupted unless we yield on await. You do need to synchronize access for some async routines which is why packages like https://pub.dev/packages/synchronized exist.

Comment: Yeah, that's for very coarse-grained locking. Takes a bit to wrap the head around this runtime model. It's the same as in the browser because Dart was initially designed to be easily transpiled to JS. More information is available for the browser https://www.google.com/search?q=browser+event+loop

Comment: Yes there's a need for it: when your variable must be `final` but you want to change it's value later...

Comment: @GuiRitter can you please elaborate? `final`'s only purpose is to prevent later changes. Perhaps `final` is not what you want in the first place.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer At least when I was working in Java, there were moments where I was using methods such as `forEach` and I wanted to update e.g. a counter that was defined outside of the lambda used in `forEach`. In that case, if I remember correctly, Java's lambdas aren't allowed to access outside variables that aren't final. In Dart's case, I wanted to update a `double` defined inside an `enum`. I tried to write my own wrapper but I found out that Dart is too strongly typed so I couldn't do it.

Comment: @GuiRitter There is no such limitation in Dart. I'm sure just omitting `final` will do what you want. `final` in Dart is really just about whether the variable can be modified after initialization and has otherwise no effect.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Generally, yes but for `enum`, no. See [`non_final_field_in_enum`](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages?utm_source=dartdev&utm_medium=redir&utm_id=diagcode&utm_content=non_final_field_in_enum#non_final_field_in_enum).